# How to activate a Chrome extension as soon as entering a website?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to make a extension, which will prevent the website from loading when entering a website. Then the extension will check if the URL of the website is in my blacklist or not. If the URL is in my blacklist, then my extension should popup a window to ask if the user still want to view the website. If the website is not in my blacklist, the extension should start to load the website.

My problem is:
I can only activate the extension by clicking the extension icon, and the loading of websites is often finished before I clicking the icon.

What should I do to activate the extension without clicking the icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`webRequest` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest), specifically [`RequestFilter`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#type-RequestFilter)

Here's an example from the docs:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function(details) {
        return {cancel: details.url.indexOf("://www.evil.com/") != -1};
    },
    {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
    ["blocking"]);
```

You would need to put this code in a background script so that it is listening to all tabs, and within the `onBeforeRequest` method you need to inject an alert into the current tab if the url is matched to your list. You can communicate between the background page and content script/current web page via chrome's [async messaging api](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-sendMessage).